# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed

Tags: asp.net, iis7

Our Sharepoint portal has been active for some years now but I'm just now getting bug reports about some controls not working. So far all problem reports are from subsidiaries - some here in Germany, others in the US.

The controls are all on UpdatePanels and cause the following error message:

```
Meldung: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near '
<!DOCTYPE html PUB'.
Zeile: 5
Zeichen: 62099
Code: 0
URI: http://portalp/ScriptResource.axd?d=tBOLY2kq1uaK6kD_aXo93OFalhL9aphke4d53_sq1dRfcIBYE0qIgcmWdYC742LMtXwFgP2IzLEYaioM3yrkYNf-n3bi_8-9pLWAF-I15SU8jWyqpTkbSR81uDJ86tOJOuR4XKJDTwjdIMIgm4FHTe7O0Ng1&t=ffffffffb868b5f4
```

I have read a number of the other posts on this subject and also the [developer blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx) but I cannot see that I am breaking any of the rules.

We are using Sharepoint 2010 on WinServer 6.1 and IIS 7.5. End users have WinXP & IE6 or Win7 & IE7.

As no one in-house has mentioned this problem, I'm assuming a firewall problem. I think if any of the above rules were being broken it would affect all users - right?

Has anyone else had this kind of problem?

**UPDATE**

Just did some tests with the firewall and think that it can be ruled out. So I'm still puzzling over this one...

Comment: Can you check the sharepoint and IIS versions in your question. This does not look like a supported combination.

Comment: Couple of questions for you... Do you use https to access your site at all ? Do you use a network load balancer or proxy server ? Ian.

Comment: Ian: no https, yes to the proxy, no sure about the balancer (but we do only have 1 sharepoint server)

Comment: Has anything changed on the Proxy server ?  You could try getting users to clear their local internet cache too.

Comment: @Shiraz Bhaiji - sorry my mistake. I've corrected the question

Comment: IE6 is an unsupported browser for SP2010: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx#supportmatrix

Answer (score 1):

We had a problem with the Update Panel and SharePoint 2007 with our Custom Web Parts. We found that when we had an update panel on the page we could not create our controls in the standard `CreateChildControls()` method without experiencing the same error. Instead we had to create them in the `Init` event. I believe this is still true for SharePoint 2010 when it comes to Update Panels.

So in our webpart we moved all code from the `CreateChildControls()` method to the `Init` event to look something like this (VB.NET):

```vb
<Guid("somereallylongguidthingie")> _
Public Class MyWebPart
  Inherits WebPartPages.WebPart


  Public Sub New()
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
    MyBase.CreateChildControls()
  End Sub

  Private Sub MyWebPart_Init(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me.Page) Is Nothing Then
      Dim Manager As New ScriptManager
      Manager.EnablePartialRendering = True
      Me.Controls.Add(Manager)
    End If

    'Rest of initialization here that would normally be in CreateChildControls Method

  End Sub

End Class
```

The ScriptManager section is added to ensure you only add one per page (as required by the Update Panel) regardless of the number of web parts requiring it that may or may not be on the page.

Answer (score 1):

IE6 is an unsupported browser for SP2010, 1 REASON BEING all the javascript SP2010 uses.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx#supportmatrix